# Migrating from Solace 8.4 to 8.5 - error at Docker startup

Tags: docker, solace

Just installed and tried to start Solace 8.5 community edition in Docker.  Had successfully been running 8.4 for weeks.  8.5 attempts to start and then dies with following error:

```
2017-09-11T18:55:36+0000  ip-10-97-56-158 root[178]: /usr/sw                        
adCmnDiskTrans.cpp:150 (ADMANAGER    - 0x00000001) main(0)@dataplane(11)                       
FATAL    file /usr/sw/internalSpool/softAdb/backingStore actual size(536870912) != 
expected size(805306368)
```

Rolling back to 8.4 runs fine.  Docker command is:

```
docker run -v /data/vmr/adb:/usr/sw/adb -v /data/vmr/internalSpool/softAdb:/usr/sw/internalSpool/softAdb -v /data/vmr/jail:/usr/sw/jail -v /data/vmr/var:/usr/sw/var -v /data/vmr/internalSpool:/usr/sw/internalSpool -v /data/vmr/diags:/var/lib/solace/diags -d --network=host --uts=host --shm-size=4g --ulimit core=-1 --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit nofile=2448:38048 --cap-add=IPC_LOCK --cap-add=SYS_NICE --env 'username_admin_globalaccesslevel=admin' --env 'username_admin_password=admin' --name=solace8.5 solace-app:8.5.0.1008-community
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because there is no upgrade path for the community edition VMR.

If you wish to migrate any message-vpn configs, generally there is a good chance of success by backing it up in CLI:

```
solace-old> show current-config message-vpn <name> > /configs/vpn-config.txt
```

and importing it in the newer release:

```
solace-new> source script /configs/vpn-config.txt stop-on-error
```

Ref: http://docs.solace.com/System-and-Software-Maintenance/Generating-CLI-Config-Sequences.htm

Note that you should empty out the volumes; don't try to use the same volumes that retained files from the older VMR on the newer VMR.